# How to connect a java program to a JSP page

Tags: java, javascript, xml, jsp, servlets

I currently have a program called JDBC 1 which connects to a mysql database. This program returns a string. I want this string to be inserted into a JSP page. However when I try to use netbeans to create a servlet it gives me a bunch of html presets. I cannot use PHP as I do not have it installed on my tomcat. I am using netbeans IDE.

This is the Java App

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class JDBCExample1 {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/maps";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "root";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
      conn = DriverManager
              .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maps","root", "root");
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      String sql = "SELECT locname,latitude,longitude FROM location";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
      while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name
         double latitude  = rs.getDouble("latitude");
         double longitude = rs.getDouble("longitude");
         String locname = rs.getString("locname");


         //Display values
         System.out.print(latitude);
         System.out.print(longitude);
         System.out.print(locname);

      }
      rs.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
      }// do nothing
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end JDBCExample1
```

Which returns a string of numbers and locations from my database. Now I want to insert that string into this JSP page so that I can create a array to populate the map with the coordinates I have extracted from the mysql database.

The JSP

```
<%-- 
    Document   : gogolemaps
    Created on : Sep 19, 2014, 12:48:35 PM
    Author     : bsebat
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var layers=[];

        layers[0] = new  google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.hpc.ncep.noaa.gov/kml/fop/fopbody.kml',
                {preserveViewport: true});

        layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/forecast/archive/latest_wsp34knt120hr_tenthDeg.kmz',
                {preserveViewport: true});

        layers[2] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_month_depth_link.kml',
                {preserveViewport: true});

        layers[3] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://activefiremaps.fs.fed.us/data/kml/conus_latest_lg_incidents.kml',
                {preserveViewport: true});

        layers[4] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://w1.weather.gov/tcig/Tornado.kml?random=115233',
                {preserveViewport: true});
        var map;


        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.744771, -73.3171305);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

            for(var i=0;i < locations.length;i++ ) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: locations[i].latlng,
                    map:map, title:locations[i].name});}
        }

        function toggleLayers(i)

        {

            if(layers[i].getMap()==null) {
                layers[i].setMap(map);
            }
            else {
                layers[i].setMap(null);
            }
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "toggleLayers("+i+") [setMap("+layers[i].getMap()+"] returns status: "+layers[i].getStatus()+"<br>";
        }


    </script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
Flood <input type="checkbox" id="layer_01" onclick="toggleLayers(0);"/>
Hurricane<input type="checkbox" id="layer_02" onclick="toggleLayers(1);"/>
Earthquake<input type="checkbox" id="layer_03" onclick="toggleLayers(2);"/>
Fire<input type="checkbox" id="layer_04" onclick="toggleLayers(3);"/>
Tornado<input type="checkbox" id="layer_05" onclick="toggleLayers(4);"/>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:800px; width:800px;"></div>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="value">
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help that you might provide  !

Comment: Too much wrong with this code to even know where to begin.  Looks like you pasted JDBCExample1 in twice and left out the JSP.  But the JDBCExample1 code is most troubling.

Comment: Well the code works correctly and returns a string. I am just asking how to get that string into the JSP page. I do not have any problems with what the code does.

Comment: "Works correctly" is immaterial to me.  You should have a lot of problems with the code.

Comment: You are probably moving too fast. You should familiarize yourself with servlets and make sure you have a strong grasp of MVC.

Comment: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html Try following a tutorial and plug in what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code doesn't `return` a string, it *prints a string to the DOS prompt style console.*   That's a **big** difference.

The simplest thing you can do is change:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

to something like:

```
public static String getString() {
```

and then instead of using `System.out.println(`, append all your output to one string (called whatever, but for now lets say `outputString`), and at the end, `return outputString;`

Then you can reference the class in your servlet and call it. `String x = JDBCExample1.getString();`

Of course *it makes more sense to just make a db class* that does nothing but retrieves a connection (i.e. has a function that returns a `Connection`), and to call this in your servlet to retrieve a connection, then do your query etc. in the servlet itself. After all, you will probably end up with many servlets, each one needing to connect to the db to do something. So a db connection class will be more useful.